# Retrieve information about SQL Server licenses

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of Microsoft SQL Servers, deployed on different serverw with versions ranging from 11 to 19. I need a way to see when the purchased license will expire. All these SQL Servers are owned by an organization and not used for personal use.

How can I achieve this via PowerShell script or via a SQL Server statement in SSMS?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```sql
SELECT @@VERSION
```

...and:

```sql
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('LicenseType') as Licensetype, 

       SERVERPROPERTY('NumLicenses') as LicenseNumber,

       SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as Productverion, 

       SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel')as ProductLevel, 

       SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') as SQLEdition,@@VERSION as SQLversion
```

...and also the scripts from the following articles:

[SQL Server License key checking](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0206e532-efe9-40d9-a5db-e2f0b759030d/sql-server-license-key-checking?forum=sqltools) (MSDN)

[How do I find out what License has been applied to my SQL Server installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099453/how-do-i-find-out-what-license-has-been-applied-to-my-sql-server-installation) (Stackoverflow)

Comment: Licensing questions are off-topic here. See https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/are-licensing-questions-within-our-scope . (That being said, the licenses themselves don't expire, but ongoing support and upgrade rights (aka "Software Assurance") _is_ time-based. But that info won't be stored in SQL. You'll need to get that info from your organization's purchasing, licensing, finance, or legal department.)

Comment: @DougDeden The question isn't about licencing, but about how to *see* the licencing from SQL Server, and how to execute such a query on multiple servers at once.

Comment: You can use this script https://www.ryadel.com/en/sql-server-retrieve-product-key-from-an-existing-installation/ in Powershell like this `GetSqlServerProductKey -targets Server1,Server2`

Comment: @Charlieface Fair enough. It's certainly in the gray area. But the title -- "... about SQL licenses" ought to be improved if they want it to not be considered off-topic. (In any case, I was just making the observation -- I didn't flag or vote.) Rick is asking for expiration dates, and from a quick look at the script in your comment it doesn't appear to provide that. Can you clarify? Or expand it into an answer?

Comment: Most licences don't really expire as such, so not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: @Charlieface what Iam looking for is the getting the licensing from sql to see if we have software assurance and number of core dedicated for the sql server. Mayne I should be more clear and ask another question. But to sum up I need licensing >> software assurance >> sql server cores

Comment: yes @DougDeden I need the SA to know if we can upgrade the sql server or not.